# Get margins of QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

Is there any way to get margins settled via Qt Style Sheets from code?

**Style Sheet:**

```
QPushButton {
    background: #E1E1E1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ADADAD;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

**Code:**

```
void QDelayPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPushButton::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter painter(this);
    QRect workRect = rect();               // Always return full button rect
    QRect rect2  = contentsRect();         // Always = workRect;
    QMargins margins = contentsMargins();  // Always 0, 0, 0, 0 (no matter what in qss)
    ...
}
```

[image: example]

UPD1:
Here is the minimalistic example:

```
QFrame b;
b.setStyleSheet( "margin: 10px;" );
b.show();
qDebug() << b.geometry() << b.contentsRect() << b.contentsMargins(); // QRect(640,280 640x480) QRect(10,10 620x460) QMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)

QPushButton b;
b.setStyleSheet( "margin: 10px;" );
b.show();
qDebug() << b.geometry() << b.contentsRect() << b.contentsMargins(); // QRect(640,280 46x35) QRect(0,0 46x35) QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: In the generated files for your GUI, or if you did it by hand in your files, `setStyleSheet()` is called. Where is that?  Can you post that code?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, stylesheets in my case set for entire application by `qApp->setStyleSheet(StyleSheet);`. See also  UPD1 in post. Think this is a bug.

Comment: Bug ticket for follow-up : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62797

Comment: @ymoreau that is my ticket :) Thanks for confirmation at linux